# simplifying an expression of the complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-series

In the [course reader](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/book-fall-07.pdf) of the EE261 class of Standford University, there's the integration of this function:

$f(t) = 
    \begin{cases} 
       +1 & \text{ if } -1/2 \leq t < 1/2\\
       -1 & \text{ if } +1/2 \leq t < 1
    \end{cases}$

Here's the steps.

\begin{align}
  c_n &= \int_0^1 e^{-2\pi int} f(t) \,dt\\
      &= \int_0^{1/2} e^{-2\pi int} \,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 e^{-2\pi int} \,dt \\
      &= \left[-\frac{1}{2\pi in}e^{-2\pi int}\right]_{0}^{1/2}
          - \left[-\frac{1}{2\pi in}e^{-2\pi int}\right]_{1/2}^{1} \tag{1}\\
      &= \frac{1}{\pi in}(1 - e^{-\pi in})\tag{2}.
\end{align}

I'm not able to go from (1) to (2).  My question is in the algebra, not in the integration.  Here's what I get.

\begin{align}
  c_n &= \int_0^1 e^{-2\pi int} f(t) \,dt\\
      &= \int_0^{1/2} e^{-2\pi int} \,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 e^{-2\pi int} \,dt \\
      &= \left[-\frac{1}{2\pi in}e^{-2\pi int}\right]_{0}^{1/2}
          - \left[-\frac{1}{2\pi in}e^{-2\pi int}\right]_{1/2}^{1}\\
      &= -\frac{1}{2\pi in}e^{\pi in} + \frac{1}{2\pi in}e^0 
         - \left( -\frac{1}{2\pi in}e^{-2\pi in} + \frac{1}{2\pi in}e^{\pi in}  \right)\\
      &= \frac{1}{2\pi in}\left(-e^{\pi in} + 1 + e^{-2\pi in} - e^{\pi in}\right)\\
      &= \frac{1}{2\pi in}\left(-2e^{\pi in} + 1 + e^{-2\pi in} \right)
\end{align}

I'm not sure how I could simplify this further to as to match the text's answer.  Can you show me what I could do here to get there?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) we get $e^{2\pi in}=\cos(2\pi n)+\sin(2\pi n)i=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Then can deduce
$$
\frac1{2\pi in}\left(-2e^{\pi in}+1+e^{-2\pi in}\right)=\frac1{2\pi in}\left(-2e^{\pi in}+1+1\right)=\frac1{2\pi in}\left(2-2e^{\pi in}\right)=\frac1{\pi in}\left(1-e^{\pi in}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the identity.  I used it a few days ago and had completely forgotten about it.  Maybe I'll never forget it again!  I once remarked to a friend that I could never be sure if "accidentally" was spelled with "tally" or "telly." "I'll keep a tally of all your spelling mistakes!", he said. Lol.  I always remember now.